# Build works in debug, fails in release - ZipException duplicate entry

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am upgrading an application from 2.3 to Nougat (SDK 25). When I add `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0` in order to support `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`. When I run this in debug mode, the applicaiton runs without issues, but running with `./gradlew assembleDebug` causes the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/hardware/display/DisplayManagerCompat.class
```

When I run this in debug mode, the application builds without issues, however, when I try to `Build APK`, I get the error above.

Is there a way I can track down the duplicate package? I ran the following:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies :dependencies --configuration compile

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0 (*)
+--- project :deps:android-map-utils:library
|    \--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
\--- project :deps:google-play-services

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)
```

Here's my `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'lib')
    compile project(':deps:google-maps-m4b')
    compile project(':deps:android-map-utils:library')
    compile project(':deps:google-play-services')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // Already hit dex limit
        multiDexEnabled true
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Files in `libs`: `armeabi/libcryptowrapper.so`
Files in `lib`:

```
ClientCertUtil.jar
apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
gcm.jar
httpclient-4.3.4.jar
httpclientandroidlib-1.2.1.jar
httpcore-4.3.jar
httpmime-4.3.1.jar
javarosa.jar
joda-time-2.0.jar
kxml2-2.3.0.jar
mgrs.jar
opencsv-2.3.jar
regexp-me.jar
zip4j_1.3.2.jar
```

When adding `exclude module: 'support-v4'` to `appcompat-v7`, build fails still and debug log shows, unable to load main activity with an `index out of bound, length: 0, index: 3`:

```
Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:(net.lingala.zip4j.unzip.Unzip$1) that doesn't come with an
Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Running

```
./gradlew -q projects

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

Root project 'opendatakit-collect'
\--- Project ':deps'
     +--- Project ':deps:android-map-utils'
     |    \--- Project ':deps:android-map-utils:library'
     +--- Project ':deps:google-maps-m4b'
     \--- Project ':deps:google-play-services'
```

Running `./gradlew :dependencies` since I don't seem to have a project name:

```
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

_debugAndroidTestAnnotationProcessor - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugAndroidTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1
     \--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1

_debugAndroidTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
\--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1
     \--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1

_debugAnnotationProcessor - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0 (*)
+--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
+--- project :deps:android-map-utils:library
|    \--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
\--- project :deps:google-play-services

_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0 (*)
+--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
+--- project :deps:android-map-utils:library
|    \--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
\--- project :deps:google-play-services

_debugUnitTestAnnotationProcessor - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugUnitTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugUnitTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseAnnotationProcessor - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0 (*)
+--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
+--- project :deps:android-map-utils:library
|    \--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
\--- project :deps:google-play-services

_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0 (*)
+--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
+--- project :deps:android-map-utils:library
|    \--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
\--- project :deps:google-play-services

_releaseUnitTestAnnotationProcessor - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseUnitTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseUnitTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

androidJacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946

androidJacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.5.201505241946
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.5.201505241946
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.5.201505241946
     |    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.5.201505241946 (*)
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.5.201505241946

androidTestAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'androidTest'.
No dependencies

androidTestApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'androidTest' classes.
No dependencies

androidTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestProvided - Classpath for only compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'androidTest'.
No dependencies

annotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'main'.
No dependencies

apk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'main' classes.
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0
|    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.0.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0
|    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.0.0 (*)
+--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
+--- project :deps:android-map-utils:library
|    \--- project :deps:google-maps-m4b
\--- project :deps:google-play-services

debugAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'debug'.
No dependencies

debugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'debug' classes.
No dependencies

debugCompile - Classpath for compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

debugProvided - Classpath for only compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

debugWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'debug'.
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
No dependencies

default-mapping - Configuration for default mapping artifacts.
No dependencies

default-metadata - Metadata for the produced APKs.
No dependencies

instrumentTestAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'instrumentTest'.
No dependencies

instrumentTestApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'instrumentTest' classes.
No dependencies

instrumentTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the instrumentTest sources.
No dependencies

instrumentTestProvided - Classpath for only compiling the instrumentTest sources.
No dependencies

instrumentTestWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'instrumentTest'.
No dependencies

provided - Classpath for only compiling the main sources.
No dependencies

releaseAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'release'.
No dependencies

releaseApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'release' classes.
No dependencies

releaseCompile - Classpath for compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

releaseProvided - Classpath for only compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

releaseWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'release'.
No dependencies

testAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'test'.
No dependencies

testApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'test' classes.
No dependencies

testCompile - Classpath for compiling the test sources.
No dependencies

testDebugAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'testDebug'.
No dependencies

testDebugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'testDebug' classes.
No dependencies

testDebugCompile - Classpath for compiling the testDebug sources.
No dependencies

testDebugProvided - Classpath for only compiling the testDebug sources.
No dependencies

testDebugWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'testDebug'.
No dependencies

testProvided - Classpath for only compiling the test sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseAnnotationProcessor - Classpath for the annotation processor for 'testRelease'.
No dependencies

testReleaseApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'testRelease' classes.
No dependencies

testReleaseCompile - Classpath for compiling the testRelease sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseProvided - Classpath for only compiling the testRelease sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'testRelease'.
No dependencies

testWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'test'.
No dependencies

wearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'main'.
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 13.053 secs

This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

Comment: Are there any libraries in the `lib` or `libs` folder? If so, please edit the question and list the jar names with as much info about the library as possible

Comment: I've updated my libs directory list, sorry for the lack of information.

Comment: Apache Commons and Joda, for example, definitely have their own Gradle libraries. Why use jar files for them?

Comment: I bet the problem is in one of the `:deps:` projects, which again, there are Gradle libraries for the Google play services, why have the the sources sitting on disk in a project?

Comment: These are legacy libraries. I will spend the time today removing them and replacing them with default gradle projects. Will get back to you.

Comment: @RijviRajib what about `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'` .By the by same type lib calling error

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I changed the version and still no luck.

Comment: It appears I have a support-v4 in `android-map-utils` dep. Unfortunately, I need to keep this dep because I use Google Maps M4B which does not work with `android-map-utils` in Gradle. I replaced the `support-v4.jar` compile and instead added a gradle line: `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'`. I added an exclude in my `compile(project(:deps:android-map-utils))` but it doesn't seem to work and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for editing the question. Since there are so many jar libs, it is almost impossible for us to replicate the error.

So, here's something to try. Since you said error came after you added the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0` lib, do the following:

```
compile (compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

See if it works or if the error changes

EDIT:

You ran the following command: `./gradlew -q dependencies :dependencies --configuration compile`

Can you run this command in your Android Studio terminal and post the `debugApk` and `releaseApk` dependencies in your question.

Command (change app to your module name if it's different):

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Comment: Build still fails, and additional errors show up in debug mode now.

Comment: The additional error that you posted is just an `InnerClass` warning. Not an error. Warning won't stop the build. After that message, it should say `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` or `BUILD FAILED`

Comment: I've edited my answer. Can you try that and post the result in your question

Comment: I've updated my answer: Did not have a project name, so ran :dependencies,

Answer (score 0):

I guess some of dependency you have added have `appcompat-v4` within it that causes the error , not quite sure

**Possible Solutions:**

- Try removing `zip4j_1.3.2.jar` , and adding again 
  `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'`
- the one proposed by @th3pat3l :  add

`compile (compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}`

**Tip for Api Versions > 14 :**

- Avoid using jar's because they are packaged and you can hardly change them , instead try to use them in build.gradle file of project by adding a simple `compile ''xxx.xx.xx`

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this kind issue when i import old eclipse project. It occurred some old dependency as jar file in the project.

First way just remove

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

in gradle file

and add dependency in the gradle file.

It works for me ..

Second way 
You've probably fixed this by now but just so this doesn't stay unanswered, Try adding this to your `build.gradle:`

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: So the configuration exclude broke my build - for some reason it didn't work properly. Instead, I used Cmd+O to find the exact class name `DisplayManagerCompat.class` and found the duplicate (a library used in one of my `:deps:`. Converted that to use gradle and then did an exclude for that specifically in the `build.gradle`for my main app

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project, and rebuilding it from Android Studio